# Send SOAP document to API endpoint

Tags: c#, web-services, serialization, soap, httpclient

I am looking to send a SOAP document to an API.

The method I want to use is to create a c# object that reflects the soap document and then convert this object to a string before using this
string as content in my HTTPContent object that I send using a HTTPClient PostAsync Method.

The structure of the SOAP document is as follows :-

```
<SOAPENV:Envelope
xmlns:SOAPENV="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"
xmlns:SOAPENC="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-encoding"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<SOAPENV:Body>
<StateRequest>
  <SourceSystem>SOURCESYSTEMHERE</SourceSystem>
  <SourcePassword>SOURCEPASSWORDHERE</SourcePassword>
  <SourceJobList>
    <SourceJobID>SOURCEJOBIDHERE</SourceJobID>
  </SourceJobList>
</StateRequest>
</SOAPENV:Body>
</SOAPENV:Envelope>
```

I want to do something like the Psuedo code below:-

```
HttpContent content = new StringContent(object.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8, "text/xml");
            content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/xml");
            _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("text/xml"));

            var response = _client.PostAsync(new Uri("http://targeturl.com "), content).Result;
```

What I want to know is

1. What c# object and attributes do I need to create to map this document structure? I need to create a C# object as I will be using data sent from 
   another source to update the SourceSystem,SourcePassword and SourceJobID properties.
2. What serialization/configuration do i need as part of the above method as I'm sure there is more required than just doing .ToString() on object.

Regards
Macca

Comment: If you copy the XML and inside visual studio in an empty class, `Edit`...`Paste Special`...`Paste XML as Classes` this will create the necessary classes for you.

Comment: Thanks Dom. Can I use.ToString() as I mention above or do I need to do some serialization of the class before using it in my HTTPContent object as shown above.

Comment: You will need to serialise it